# Zabbix - get output of simple check for VMware Hypervisors Discovery

Tags: vmware, zabbix

Zabbix 6.2 offers nice tools for vCenter, Hypervisors and VM monitoring. I try to debug some of my own template LLDs, and would like to see json that's returned by `vmware.hv.discovery[{$VMWARE.URL}]` key - but can't find a way for.

The problem is, as per [documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/en/manual/vm_monitoring/vmware_keys), the `vmware.hv.discovery` is a simple check, and simple checks are done by server itself not by agents so I can't just use `zabbix_get` on it.

**Please advice how to get simple check output!**

Comment: i don't think there is currently a way to get `vmware.*` output... try raising the debug level and check if the output is written in the logs (then remember to lower the debug level when you are done)

Comment: @ironBishop Just did that by set loglevel to 5 and got string from the server: indeed, zabbix-server 6.2 returns IP under both "{#HV.NAME}" and "{#HV.IP}".